# Grails save not respect flush option

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails as a poor man's etl tool for migrating some relatively small db objects from 1 db to the next.  I have a controller that reads data from one db (mysql) and writes it into another (pgsql).  They use similar domain objects, but not exactly the same ones due to limitations in the multi-datasource support in grails 2.1.X.

Below you'll see my controller and service code:

```
class GeoETLController {

    def zipcodeService

      def migrateZipCode() {
        def zc = zipcodeService.readMysql();
        zipcodeService.writePgSql(zc);

        render{["success":true] as JSON}
    }
}
```

And the service:

```
class ZipcodeService {

    def sessionFactory
    def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP

    def readMysql() {
        def zipcode_mysql = Zipcode.list();
        println("read, " + zipcode_mysql.size());
        return zipcode_mysql;
    }

    def writePgSql(zipcodes) {

        List<PGZipcode> zips = new ArrayList<PGZipcode>();
        println("attempting to save, " + zipcodes.size());
        def cntr = 0;
        zipcodes.each({ Zipcode zipcode ->
            cntr++;

            def props = zipcode.properties;
            PGZipcode zipcode_pg = new PGZipcode(zipcode.properties);

            if (!zipcode_pg.save(flush:false)) {
                zipcode_pg.errors.each {
                    println it
                }
            }
            zips.add(zipcode_pg)
            if (zips.size() % 100 == 0) {
                println("gorm begin" + new Date());
                // clear session here.
                this.cleanUpGorm();
                println("gorm complete" + new Date());

            }

        });
        //Save remaining
        this.cleanUpGorm();
        println("Final ." + new Date());
    }

    def cleanUpGorm() {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        session.flush()
        session.clear()
        propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
    }
}
```

Much of this is taken from my own code and then tweaked to try and get similar performance as seen in http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/

So, in reviewing my code, whenever zipcode_pg.save() is invoked, an insert statement is created and sent to the database.  Good for db consistency, bad for bulk operations.

What is the cause of my instant flushes (note: My datasource and congig groovy files have NO relevant changes)?  At this rate, it takes about 7 seconds to process each batch of 100 (14 inserts per second), which when you are dealing with 10,000's of rows, is just a long time...

Appreciate the suggestions.

**NOTE: I considered using a pure ETL tool, but with so much domain and service logic already built, figured using grails would be a good reuse of resources.  However, didn't imagine this quality of bulk operations**

Comment: Have you profiled your code to verify that the db interaction is the bottleneck? I ask because your code looks fine. I've seen some bug related to using the validate and flush options together, but not just flush alone. 14 inserts a second seems very, very slow.

Comment: I've run my code while in "debug mode" to ensure that it is in fact insert statements that are happening on each save (aka, ran a select count(*) from db pre-save() and then post-save() and saw n+1). I also have used timing statements to ensure that it is the saving portions that are slow. I suppose the bottle neck COULD be on the DB end of the situation, but even an underperforming database should not see that level of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your domain objects, this is just a hunch, but I might try specifying validate:false as well in your save() call. Validate() is called by save(), unless you tell Grails not to do that. For example, if you have a unique constraint on any field in your PGZipcode domain object, Hibernate has to do an insert on every new record to leverage the DBMS's unique function and perform a proper validation. Other constraints might require DBMS queries as well, but only unique jumps to mind right now.

From [Grails Persistence: Transaction Write-Behind](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#persistenceBasics)

> Hibernate caches database updates where possible, only actually
>   pushing the changes when it knows that a flush is required, or when a
>   flush is triggered programmatically. **One common case where Hibernate
>   will flush cached updates is when performing queries since the cached
>   information might be included in the query results.** But as long as
>   you're doing non-conflicting saves, updates, and deletes, they'll be
>   batched until the session is flushed.

---

Alternately, you might try setting the Hibernate session's [flush mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html) explicitly:

```
sessionFactory.currentSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
```

I'm under the impression the default flush mode might be AUTO.

Comment: no help. my save call is now zipcode_pg.save(flush:false, validate: false).

Comment: Bummer. I've had success finding the source of issues like this by following the stack into Hibernate land. If you turn on debug logging for Hibernate (org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl might be a good class to start with), you can key into the path that's triggering SessionImpl.flush()